# laravel - inserting id from one table to another right after submitting a form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

Since I'm new in Laravel (started using this framework 2 weeks ago), I'm having a hard time inserting an id from one table to another right after submitting a form.

The scenario is that I have a form and what I wanted is that the id **(p_id)** of the newly submitted data from the **1st table (packages table)** will be inserted to the **2nd table (itineraries table)**. Below are the codes of my controller and my model:

#### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
    request()->validate([
        'packageName' => 'required',
        'adultPrice' => 'required',
        'childPrice' => 'required',
        'infantPrice' => 'required',
        'excessPrice' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'inclusions' => 'required',
        'additionalInfo' => 'required',
        'reminders' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'required',
        'tags' => 'required',
        'noOfDays' => 'required',
        'day' => 'required',
        'time' => 'required',
        'destination' => 'required'
    ]);
    Packages::create($request->all());
    Itinerary::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('Agent.Packages');
}
```

#### Itinerary Model

```
class Itinerary extends Model{
   public $fillable = [
       'noOfDays',
       'day',
       'time',
       'destination',
       ];
}
```

Comment: From where did you get inserted package ID ?

Comment: whot you mean with id ? if you dont have it in request you have to right after creating table do this :  `Packages::all()->latest()->p_id`  and you are done store it into `$p_id` for example and do with it whot you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The create method returns the saved model instance.

```
$package = Packages::create($request->all());
```

After that you can use it to populate the `Itinerary` table however you want.

```
$itinerary =  new Itinerary();
$itinerary->package_id = $package->id;
// Populate other fields
$itinerary->save();
```

Since you're new to Laravel, I would propose to use the `->save()` method to populate it. In my opinion, it's clearer in telling what you want to do in the code.

Comment: when i used this first time it insert 0 value. why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

To insert Data from first table to second table,
First of all you need to get the last Insert Id.

Change your code as follows:

```
$package = Packages::create($request->all());
$p_id = $package->id;    // You will get your Id.
// Later you need to add it to below method.
$data = array_merge($p_id,$request->all());   // I`m not sure about this line...
Itinerary::create($data);
```